# Alternating Sum Using FOLDR (SML)

Tags: list, sml, fold

I'm trying to use `foldr` to get an alternating sum from a list of `int`, but keep getting an operator/operand mismatch error. I have a feeling that I'm not completely understanding `foldr`

```
l = [1,3,5,7,9]
foldr (op-) l
```

I'm expecting to have the output be

```
1 - 3 + 5 - 7 + 9 = 5
```

EDIT:

I am actually being asked to use an anonymous function with `foldr`

So, for example

```
l = [1,3,5,7,9]
foldr (fn (x, y): => x - y) l
```

With the same expected output, but I'm still getting the same operand/operator mismatch

Comment: Check the type of `foldr`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`foldr` (as well as `foldl`) take an initial value.

The type of `foldr` is `('a * 'b -> 'b) -> 'b -> 'a list -> 'b`, where `'b` is the type of the result of each step in folding (as well as the initial value, which is the initial "result"); and `'a` is the type of the elements in the list. Note that `'a` and `'b` can be different. The combining function takes an element and a previous result and returns the new result.

Anyway, you need to think of an appropriate initial value. What should it be? I think 0 would do:

```
foldr op- 0 l
```

Comment: If the OP needs to use an anonymous function it should be `foldr (fn (x,y) => x - y) 0` but obviously `(op-)` is better.

Comment: What does the `0` do?

Comment: @Delfini: Maybe you should look at the documentation for `foldr`, or read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_%28higher-order_function%29

Answer (score 1):

A solution using only the `List.foldl` function is the following.

```
fun altSum ls = if (List.foldl op+ 0 (map (fn x => 1) ls)) mod 2 = 0 
                then ~1 * (List.foldl (fn (x, y) => y - x) 0 ls)
                else List.foldl (fn (x, y) => y - x) 0 ls
```

You can see why this works [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27306401/2129306).